# How to set point labels in a scatter plot?

Tags: plotting, labeling

How to type each label in the upper right position? For example adding `{0.25,0.25}` to each point.

```
 primeirocolor = RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798];
 lista = Table[{RandomInteger[{1, 5}], RandomInteger[{1, 8}]}, {i, 1, 8}]

 nomes = {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight"}

 ListPlot[ MapThread[Labeled, {lista, nomes}]]

 lp = Labeled[  ListPlot[   MapThread[Labeled, {lista, nomes}], PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize -> .016},    PlotTheme -> "Detailed", LabelStyle -> {20, Bold},    ImageSize -> Full]  , {Rotate["Oposición", Pi/2], "Baremo"}, {Left, Bottom},   LabelStyle -> {32, Bold}]
```

Answer (score 3):

It may be easier to use the offset argument of`Text`. In the following I  try to illustrate this. I have not dealt with the duplicate issue (i.e. the same integer pair being generated). Using the variables in OP:

```
nomes = {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", 
  "Eight"}
off[x_, y_] := 
 Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.02], Point@lista, Blue, 
   MapThread[Text[#1, #2, {x, y}] &, {nomes, lista}]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 9}, {0, 9}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
Manipulate[
 off[offset[[1]], offset[[2]]], {{a, 0}, -1, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{offset, {0, 0}}, {-5, -5}, {5, 5}, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The third argument of Labeled is the control of positions, as in format {object_pos, label_pos}. label_pos will be {0, 0} because you want the left-bottom corner of the label to be placed at the right-top corner, that is {1, 1} for the object_pos.

`ListPlot[{Labeled[{1, 1}, "test", {{1, 1}, {0, 0}}]}]`

[image]